# fstream does not function in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, fstream, ifstream, ostream

I am new in Qt. I have my project coded in visual C++ 2010 express edition which works totally fine. Then, I want to use .cpp files that I already created in Qt console application (similar to my project in VC++2010). Compiling fails at "ofstream" and "ifstream" with this error:

```
"no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::basic_strinstream<char>::_string_type)'"
"no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::string&)'"
```

I have included fstream to the cpp file as:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
```

and the piece of the code which fails is as follows:

```
stringstream s1; s1 << "Estimated_NN_ThrMWh.csv";
ofstream outF1(s1.str());
```

By the way, I am using "MinGW 4.9.1 32bit" as my compiler. What is the issue and how can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want `ofstream outF1(s1.str().c_str());`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. But the same exact code works fine when I compile in VC++2010. I am wondering why it does not work in Qt.

Comment: @seyyedalipourmousavi "*I have my project coded in visual C++ 2010 express edition which works totally fine.*" Then why not keep using MSVC compiler in Qt?

Comment: @Tay2510: How can I add MSVC compiler in Qt?

Comment: @seyyedalipourmousavi **Qt Creator** -> **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Compilers**. You should be able to see MSVC compiler auto-detected if you have it, otherwise you'll have to manually add one. See: https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-tool-chains.html

Comment: Thanks, I had MSVC compiler auto-detected and I could use it to compile the code without any issue. Thanks for your comment.
But what if I want to use Windows SDK 7.1 since it works with Windows 64 bit and I need it to use with Gurobi? I have SDK 7.1 installed on my machine, but it does not show in Qt. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @seyyedalipourmousavi Not sure what you mean about "*SDK 7.1 does not show in Qt*". SDK 7.1 is just a collection package of codes, libraries, and some APIs (a free MSVC compiler also). If you'd like to use it, just link the libraries to your project and include the headers in your codes. I guess perhaps it's because in Visual C++ you can "see" it and interact with it through convenient UI, but actually what they did behind the scene is just linking those libraries for you.

Comment: When I go to Qt Creator -> Tools -> Options -> Compilers, I can see Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (ia64) auto-detected. My understanding is that I should be able to build my console application in Qt using this compiler, is it correct? If so, then why there is no kit so that I can use to compile my project? (I can use MinGW and MVSC 2010 in "Projects" Build & Run)

Comment: @seyyedalipourmousavi Go Qt Creator -> Tools -> Options -> (I miss a **Build & Run**)-> Kits and add a new kit, then select MSVC as the compiler of the kit. Besides, you also need to assign the debugger for it (SDK 7.1 also provide a debugger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a `std::string` to the `std::ofstream` constructor. This is [a C++11 feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) and to use this you need to pass `-std=c++11` to GCC or Clang. MSVC automatically compiles for its hybrid not-quite-C++11-or-anything-else language that the compiler release compiles.

If you're using Qt 5's qmake, you can do just `CONFIG+=c++11` and you're good to go. Otherwise you'll need something like

```
*gcc*:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

If you don't want to depend on C++11, don't use it, and just do:

```
std::string filename("Estimated_NN_ThrMWh.csv");
std::ofstream outF1(filename.c_str());
```

which will always work. Note I removed the stringstream because, at least in the short code you show, it's superfluous.

Comment: You want `filename.c_str()` there.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Right-o. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

you should always write as following:

```
string s = s1.str();
ofstream outF1(s);
```

And, in my opinion, You code works under MSVC should be considered as a bug of MSVC (which allows non-const reference bind to a temporary object).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I use stringstream because I modify file name based on some parameters of my simulation in the original code. For example, it could be something like this:
    stringstream s1; s1 << "X_values_training_" << No_days <<"_" << No_Months << ".csv";
So I guess I cannot use string type as you mentioned.

Comment: But the two statements that I given equal to the ill-formated statement you used `ofstream outF1(s1.str());` Isn't it?

Comment: yes and it does not work under MinGW 4.9.1 compiler. I changed the compiler to MSVC 2010 and it is working just fine in the original format.

Comment: I have no idea. It compiles very well under my envrionment. gcc version 4.8.2 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project)